# File downloaded from FileResult API does not preserve original filename/extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have created a .Net core web api to return a file from a folder location by passing the folder path and file name.

The API method looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet("GetFile/{FileName}")]        
    public FileResult GetFile(string FileName)
    {
        Stream stream = FileHandler.GetFile(_filePath, FileName);
        return File(stream, "application/octet-stream");
    }
```

and the GetFile method:

```
    public static Stream GetFile(string FilePath, string FileName)
    {
        string FullFileName = Path.Combine(FilePath, FileName);
        if (File.Exists(FullFileName))
            return File.OpenRead(FullFileName);
        else
            return null;
    }
```

The problem is, the file that gets downloaded does not preserve it's original filename/extension.

if the original file name is `Sam.pdf`

the downloaded file has a name of

```
application_octet-stream_Sam.pdf_blob_https___localhost_44359_414218de-9fa5-40a4-b5d7-dcc3e3f60370
```

Due to this, the file is not opening in client side. I can not force the file encoding to 'application/pdf' because there could be different types of file extensions in the folder.

What is the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer after some research.

Passing the file name in the Return file method as 3rd parameter will do the trick.

```
[HttpGet("GetFile/{FileName}")]        
public FileResult GetFile(string FileName)
{
    Stream stream = FileHandler.GetFile(_filePath, FileName);
    return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", FileName);
}
```